# Inno Setup - bcdedit is not working

Tags: windows, inno-setup, bcdedit

I need to submit the command:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

but it's not working with Inno Setup.

I have tried as below:

```
[Setup]
PrivilegesRequired=admin

[Run]
Filename: "{cmd}"; Parameters: "/c ""bcdedit.exe /set recoveryenabled No""";
```

But I still see the `No` is not applied. As you can see below, it still remains `Yes`. But when I manually do the same command from command prompt, it works. Any idea why it is not working within Inno Setup? I'm also running the `setup.exe` as administrator.

```
C:\windows\system32>bcdedit /v

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  en-GB

integrityservices       Enable

timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------

device                  partition=C:
path                    \windows\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 8.1
locale                  en-GB

integrityservices       Enable
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \windows

nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
quietboot               Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons. It's difficult to tell as you didn't provide much information to debug this.

Using `/K` instead of `/C` is the first step, as it will keep the `cmd.exe` window open, so that you can see, if there are any error messages.

---

When I use your `[Run]` section entry in a trivial installer, I get:

> 'bcdedit.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

On my system (and I believe it would be the same on yours), it's because I'm running Windows 64-bit and the `bcdedit.exe` is in `C:\Windows\System32`. As Inno Setup in a 32-bit application, it by default [gets redirected to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector) (32-bit version of `C:\Windows\System32`). And there's no 32-bit version of `bcdedit.exe`.

Add `Flags: 64bit` to make Inno Setup find 64-bit version of `bcdedit.exe`.

Also, there's no point running `.exe` application via command interpreter (`cmd.exe`).

```
[Run]
Filename: "bcdedit.exe"; Parameters: "/set recoveryenabled No"; Flags: 64bit
```

---

Or use [64-bit install mode](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=32vs64bitinstalls).